# having trouble with sql about movie theme

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Movie(mID int, title text, year int, director text);
Reviewer(rID int, name text);
Rating(rID int, mID int, stars int, ratingDate date);
```

For each director, return the director's name together with the title(s) of the movie(s) they directed that received the highest rating among all of their movies, and the value of that rating. Ignore movies whose director is NULL.

I am stuck at highest rating part.

```
select title, director
from Movie natural join Rating
where director is not NULL
```

i know i just couldn't really write it.

Comment: Show the SQL code you have so far.

Comment: And do not look for help with your homework here. We are not here to write code on your behalf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct director, title, stars
from (movie join rating using (mid)) m
where stars in (select max(stars) 
                from rating join movie using (mid) 
                where m.director = director);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using a subquery with the `max` aggregate:

```
select m.title, m.director, r.stars
from movie m
    join rating r on m.mid = r.mid
    join (select director, max(stars) maxstars
          from rating join movie on rating.mid = movie.mid
          group by director) maxr on m.director = maxr.director
                          and r.stars = maxr.maxstars
where m.director is not null
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/924544/3)

---

Edited when I realized you need to `group by director` instead of `movie` to get the `max(stars)` per director.

Comment: I think it will duplicate the output if the same movie has multiple Ratings